# OpenApi: How to define cookie in response?

Tags: openapi, oas3

OpenApi allows to define cookies in **request** parameters. But for response all I could find is either custom headers (signal general presence of Set-Cookie, but no clue about particular cookie) or rolling custom extension (which is also very limiting, eg. lacks type and `description`).

How to define **response** cookies?

Answer (score 1):

The [OAS](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#response-object) does not mention anything special for cookies in responses.

The [swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/) are providing an example how to define the cookies for authentication. But it is generally usable for all kind of cookies.

```yaml
  responses:
    '200':
      description: >
        Successfully authenticated.
        The session ID is returned in a cookie named `JSESSIONID`. You need to include this cookie in subsequent requests.
      headers: 
        Set-Cookie:
          schema: 
            type: string
            example: JSESSIONID=abcde12345; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I've meant by "signaling general presence of Set-Cookie, but no clue about particular cookie".

Comment: Also, I wouldn't call it "defining" - it's more of a guideline than actual rule. Which is the opposite of the goal of OAS: "allows both humans and computers to (...) understand".

Comment: I understand that my answer is not satisfying, but there is no way to define a particular cookie (at least until today). I had the same question like you and that's what I found. So I thought it would help others with the same question.